# Is it possible to enable MSMQ from PowerShell on Windows 8?

Tags: powershell, windows-8, msmq, windows-8.1

Is it possible to enable [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx) from PowerShell on Windows 8(.1)? If so, how does one do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure, when using the GUI, you would use the 'Windows Features' dialog through the control panel:

[image]

To do the same thing in PowerShell you can use the `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` cmdlet.

You need to know the internal feature names, to get these, run:

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature –Online  | ? FeatureName -match "msmq" | select FeatureName
```

you get something like this:

```
FeatureName
-----------
MSMQ-Container
MSMQ-Server
MSMQ-Triggers
MSMQ-ADIntegration
MSMQ-HTTP
MSMQ-Multicast
MSMQ-DCOMProxy
WCF-MSMQ-Activation45
```

Now you can install the features you like:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MSMQ-HTTP
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MSMQ-Server
...
```

Some features have dependencies on other features, to solve them, add the `-All` switch, which installs any dependencies automatically.